# Windows Server DNS returns .local address

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows server set up as a webserver but I am also running my DNS on the same machine (I know this is bad practice). I have the domains default zone webserver.hosting.local as well as my website zone example.com. Now whenever I dig ns example.com it returns webserver.hosting.local. as one of my name servers. What do I need to configure to stop this from happening? I note that webserver.hosting.local is an ns record on the default zone.

Comment: Question - Have you tried to dig a public DNS server?

Comment: Yea I've used google (8.8.8.8) and this website http://www.kloth.net/services/dig.php, both include the .local address in the ns records.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://serverfault.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://serverfault.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried everything from restarting the dns service to clearing the cache but nothing worked. Finally solved it by rebooting the server which caused the .local ns record to show up in the wrong zone. I then removed it and its all working correctly.